# Set a gon variable from the /lib directory in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to figure out how to use the 'gon' gem to set a gon.variable within a /lib file in my Rails application. For some reason, it seems to work when I set the variable within a controller - but not within a /lib file - even when I use `require 'gon'` in the /lib file.

Is it possible to define a gon.variable from the /lib directory? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Controller is a best place for setting any data presenting on the views. You could pass a gon variable as argument to your lib method, but that is not a good solution.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do it the other way around - define a gon variable in my lib method, then pass it to the controller. Is this possible?

Comment: Try to find out a class of gon variable, using debugger (ruby-debug) for example. Then you should be able to find class in gon repository ( https://github.com/gazay/gon/tree/master/lib/gon ) and check if You could initialize it manually.